# Why Spark RDD is invariant in T?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, covariance

I would like to be able to do stuff like this

```
abstract class Super()
class Type1() extends Super
class Type2() extends Super

val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(new Type1()))
val rdd2= sc.parallelize(Seq(new Type2()))
val union = rdd1.union(rdd2)
```

If RDD was covariant on T union would be RDD[Super], but this is not even compiling. Is there any reason for the RDD to be invariant in T?

Comment: Can't answer about the why, but you can do `Seq[Super](new Type1())`, for example. Not pretty but works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This "won't-fix" JIRA ticket explains it all](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1296).

---

Because Stack Overflow dislikes just linking to an answer, here is the gist of it.

- Although RDDs expose an immutable interface to the user, there is a lot of mutability in the internal state, which would require sprinkling downcasts all over the place.
- Interactions with `Map` (invariant in the key) and `Array` (invariant) would be much more awkward (and almost certainly not backwards compatible)
- Covariance means Spark doesn't know until runtime what is actually going into the RDD, which makes interaction with other libraries (namely pickling) more complicated.

Comment: Do you think there is any chance this will ever be available for spark 2.0 Datasets (as opposed to RDD's) or would those have the same compatibility issues?

Comment: @combinatorist Nope. Spark 2.2 is out and Datasets, just like RDDs are invariant. The same constraints I mentioned in my answer still hold for Datasets.